# Redirect digest request to active directory

Tags: c#, http, redirect, active-directory, digest-authentication

I am trying to redirect an http request with digest MD5 header information to an active directory to validate the credentials.

I do have the information given by the http header like nonce and username. My problem now is that I have no link to put this information into a `PrincipalContext` object.

I obviously can't use PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials(username, password) cause it requires the password in plain text.

The only validation that I am able to use is `UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username);`, but this does not include the password.

I do have a `HttpListenerContext` object. But the user variable is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tim once you get the information you can do something like this to check if is Valid or not If I am understanding what you want to test properly then try something like this

if you are running this via code or a service you should have no issues with the password in regards to being exposed ..if you are concerned about that then you need to write something that will decrypt the MD5 Header Information where the pass word is.

```
using(PrincipalContext prContext= new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "Your Domain"))
{
    bool isValid = prContext.ValidateCredentials("Username", "Password");
}
```

Comment: I am not concerned about exposing the password. Actually I don't know the password. My client sends my a digest request having the md5 nonce piggybag. I like not to decode that md5 but immediately using that string to validate against the active directory

Comment: the answer I have provide will allow you to Validate but you have to write something that decrypts the md5 I don't believe that AD supports passing in or injecting MD5

Comment: You cannot decrypt MD5 easily. Thats why its used for decryption.

Comment: I am quite aware of that.. but that is the only code I can think of to do what you are needing to do.. also is the System behind the DMZ..? if so then exposed passwords shouldn't be an issue if this is internal to the company on their Intranet..

Answer (score 1):

After I told my server to user AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication he automaticaly deliveres a WindowsPrincipal, which provides information from the AD.

Comment: can you show example? how you forward MD5 header?